# Flutter: How should iterate in an inner loop

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a List which in this List the second element of map is another list I want have ListView of element in first List and a GridView of second or inner List How should I do this.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> myList = [
{
  'title': 'first',
  'icon': [
    item1,
    item2,
    item3,
    item4,
    item5,
  ],
},
 {
  'title': 'second',
  'icon': [
    item1,
    item2,
    item3,
    item4,
    item5,
  ],
},
```

];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the 'icon' value to a `List<YourType>` and then iterate from there.

```
    List<Map<String, Object>> myList = [
      {
        'title': 'first',
        'icon': [
          "item1",
          "item2",
          "item3",
          "item4",
          "item5",
        ],
      },
      {
        'title': 'second',
        'icon': [
          "item1",
          "item2",
          "item3",
          "item4",
          "item5",
        ],
      },
    ];
    myList.forEach((element) {
      (element['icon'] as List<String>).forEach((innerElement) {
        print(innerElement);
      });
    });
```